On simplifying the creation of custom input ranges
In Python, it is very convenient to create custom iterators (which are actually input iterators) – just write a __next__() method.
In C++, the iterator protocol is much more complex – for an iterable, you need to create begin() and end() methods, write a nested iterator class, which defines the types: value_type difference_type, etc., and has the operators ++(preincrement and postincrement), *, == (both with the iterator itself and with its sentinel). Accordingly, creating custom input ranges is not very convenient, although using such ranges is very appropriate in a number of tasks (parsers, working with  databases, etc.).
But most of the actions to create custom input ranges are routine.
Why doesn't the std have tools to make creating custom input ranges easier? For example we could:

declare that an input_range iterable should have a next() method that returns a value of type std::optional<elem_type>, where:
elem_type – the type of elements of the iterable,
bool(value) = false, where the iterable is exhausted, otherwise, value.value() is the value of the next element of the iterable.

add to std an adapter for iterable that will implement the required C++ iterator protocol. The code for such an adapter won't be too complicated - something like:
 template <typename  iterable_type> class TIterableWrapper
 {
 private:
     iterable_type&             iterable;
     using                      elem_type = typename decltype(std::declval<iterable_type>().next())::value_type;
     std::optional<elem_type>   value;

 public:
     TIterableWrapper(iterable_type& _iterable) : iterable(_iterable)
     {
         value = iterable.next();
     }

 class iterator
 {
 private:
     TIterableWrapper*   wrapper_ptr;

     iterator(TIterableWrapper*  _wrapper_ptr) : wrapper_ptr(_wrapper_ptr)
     {
     }
     friend class TIterableWrapper<iterable_type>;
 public:
     using iterator_category = std::input_iterator_tag;
     using value_type        = elem_type;
     using reference         = value_type&;
     using difference_type   = std::ptrdiff_t;

     iterator& operator++()
     {
         wrapper_ptr->value = wrapper_ptr->iterable.next();
         return (*this);
     }

     void operator++(int)
     {
        ++(*this);
     }

     const reference& operator*() const
     {
         return  wrapper_ptr->value.value();
     }

     bool operator==(const iterator& rhs) const
     {
         return this == &rhs;
     }

     bool operator==(std::default_sentinel_t) const
     {
         return !bool(*wrapper_ptr);
     }
 };

 operator bool() const
 {
     return bool(value);
 }

 auto begin()  noexcept
 {
     return  iterator(this);
 }

 auto end() const noexcept
 {
     return  std::default_sentinel;
 }

};


(unlike istream_view, when calling begin(), iterable's next() is not called (*stream_ >> value,  enter link description here),
which allow us to write code like:
class TMyIterable
{
private:
    int  count;
    int  iter_number{ 0 };
public:
    TMyIterable(int _count) : count(_count)
    {
    }

    std::optional<int> next()
    {
        return (iter_number < count) ? std::optional<int>(iter_number++) : std::nullopt;
    }
};

void TEST_TIterableWrapper()
{
    TMyIterable                     my_iterable(10);
    TIterableWrapper<TMyIterable>   
    my_iterable_wrapper(my_iterable);
    auto                            view1 = my_iterable_wrapper | std::views::take(5);
    auto                            view2 = my_iterable_wrapper | std::views::take(5);
    std::ranges::copy(view1, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));
    std::cout << "\n";
    std::ranges::copy(view2, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "- "));
}

without fear of losing elements of the iterable (the problem of input ranges like istream or std::generator when working with std::views, which Barry mentioned in enter link description here)
Then creating custom input ranges in C++ programs will be no less simple and convenient than in Python programs.

Possible duplicate: Turning the next(), hasNext() iterator interface into begin(), end() interface

Do you have a question?

Also, your use of std::optional<elem_type> assumes copying every element. That is a non-starter for a large number of C++ users/libraries.

@Botje Could you please give an example where there will be copying

For example, in your TIterableWrapper constructor: value = iterable.next();

@Botje I'm sorry, but there is a move here (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator%3D)

The problem stems from the next() method itself. Assume I have a container with a T that is several megabytes in size. The next() method signature forces me to either move those T objects out of the container, effectively emptying the original container, or make an expensive copy. And that is assuming the type is copyable or move/copy-constructible in the first place!

@Botje - I was talking only about pure input ranges (like generator and istream). The std has enough tools to model almost any container a programmer needs, but for pure input ranges there is nothing like Python's next() method.  That's why I raised the question of why std doesn't have an adapter for pure input ranges, although it's not at all difficult to write.

... Because the C++ committee standardised on iterator pairs thirty years ago and there is no point in adapting a different iterator approach since you can trivially write an adapter? "pure input ranges" are not as common as you make them out to be.

@Botje - But an istream_view was added to the std. This is practically the same thing I am talking about, only for a much narrower set of iterables. For programmers who came to C++ from Python, it is surprising to see that in such a wonderful language as C++, you have to write a lot of routine code where in Python it is enough to write one method next().

At this point I can only point you to this duplicate. If you really care about it that much, write a boost library or submit a C++ extension proposal.

This question is similar to: Turning the next(), hasNext() iterator interface into begin(), end() interface. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

In Python, it's probably still more common to write a generator function using yield instead of writing a custom class with a __next__ method.
The direct equivalent in C++23 is the range generator.
If you don't have C++23 yet, the C++20 iota_view will handle most of the boilerplate. You just need to write a type that's incrementable (equivalent to __next__), convertible to the value type you want, and optionally comparable to some sentinel.
Otherwise just use the Boost.Iterator generator_iterator.

Modeling an iterable object using a generator is good when the object is simple. But when the object is quite complex (it has several methods, we  have to write an iterator.

Especially when it is complex the generator approach stands out. All that implicit state for traversing the data structure is captured in the stack frame. A pre-order tree traversal can be as simple as yield self.value; yield from self.left.iter(); yield from self.right.iter(). The equivalent iterator is much more annoying to write.

There's also support for writing your own iterators in the Boost.Iterator library, if you do really want that. It's just not the most direct route to a custom input range, which is what you asked for.

@Botje - I like generators :) I meant the following -
if you can't implement all the functionality of an iterable object in one method, then using a generator doesn't look so elegant.
Yes, of course, you can add a method to an iterable object that returns
std::generator, but then you will have to iterate not on the object itself, but on the specified method, i.e. not in the same way as for other iterable objects (ranges, views, etc.). Well, with generators  you won't be able to use the full power of std::view

Maybe you could explain which particular powers of the view you have in mind. You only asked about input ranges: do you want random access or something?

@Useless - The generator can't work with views properly. Please see this excellent Barry’s answer -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79040286/how-do-i-reuse-a-c23-stdgenerator-instance-as-a-range-in-multiple-range-ex/79040350#79040350.

Yes, that answer points out that a generator models an input range. You asked for an input range. It's the title of your question.

You also used Python custom iterators implementing only __next__ as your example - that also only supports single-pass use.

Hang on, you followed up in a comment with "I was talking only about pure input ranges (like generator and istream)". Why do you now object to generators because they're pure input ranges?

@Useless - The std has enough tools for random access iterators  I asked why std doesn't have an adapter for iterables, for iteration of which it is enough to write one method, like Python's next(). Regarding generators - I just mentioned that I wrote the adapter example so that it would be free of the shortcomings that the generator has (incomplete work with std::views)

Can you please explain what specific property of generators you consider a shortcoming with respect to the question you asked. I'm tired of trying to guess what issue you see, and it seems like you're just continuously changing the question so that no solution other than your own is suitable.
